# how to assign some string value to the object type blank element

Tags: pandas, nan

I got error if I use the code below to select the blank element, also no change on the value if I use row['col'] == np.nan / 'nan' /'NaN' etc.

col is an object type, and I'd like to assign val = str('...') to these blank elements

```
if np.isnan(row['col']) == True:
   val = str('somewords')
```

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? Are you just trying to replace your blank values?

Comment: yeah, fill blanks with some strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

you need loc accessor with boolean masking:

```
row.loc[row['col'].isna(),'col']='somewords'
          #^                            ^
#checking if the the value is NaN     then assigning value
```

OR

with numpy's `where()` method:

```
row['col']=np.where(row['col'].isna(),'somewords',row['col'])
                      #^                  ^            ^
#checking if the the value is NaN.  
                            # then assigning value
                                                  #If not then get the original value
```

OR

via `fillna()` method(but it will fail in that case when you want to conditionally fill NaN's):

```
row['col']=row['col'].fillna('somewords')
```